# android values upload database with json

Tags: android, json, database, tags, sensors

I created MAGNETIC_FIELD sensor. this code giving x y z event values, ArithmeticAvg and SQRTx^2+y^2+z^2
i have to upload database these values. how can i upload database these values with json or something else. here my code

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SensingTextView tv = new SensingTextView(this);
    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sm.registerListener(tv,
            sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);


    setContentView(tv);



}


public class SensingTextView extends TextView implements SensorEventListener {
    public SensingTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {



        String newstr = String.format("x: %f\ny:%f\nz:%f\n\nSQRTx^2+y^2+z^2: %f\n\nArithmeticAvg: %f",
                new Object[] { event.values[0],event.values[1],event.values[2],Math.sqrt(((event.values[0] * event.values[0])
                                + (event.values[1] * event.values[1]) + (event.values[2] * event.values [2]))),
                        ((event.values[0] + event.values[1] + event.values[2])/3)
                         } );

        setText(newstr);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload your values to **mySql** database here is the steps :

1 - create table on the server with the fields needed.

2 - write php or any server side code to get the values from client

3 - implement the code in android

**JOSNParser.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

in upload code in activity like this - assumed you have a button to send data.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {    


    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    Button sendData;
    JSONObject json;

private static String url_create_user = "http://localhost/android_connect/getData.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sendData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.send);

    sendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                new CreateNewUser().execute();

        }
    });




class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Uploading data...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();


    }   


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        //get here your valuse like String values = "your data"

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("values", values));

        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_user, "POST", params);

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                   //write something in log file

            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if(json != null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The data has been sent successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to send data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


}
```

}

This line :

```
private static String url_create_user = "http://localhost/android_connect/getData.php";
```

**means : yourserver/foldername(in which the file)/php file to get the data**

**getData.php**

```
<?php
//connect to server

$con = mysql_connect(db_name, user_name, password) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
$db = mysql_select_db(db_name) or die(mysql_error());


// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['values']) ) {

    $_values = $_POST['values'];


    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_name(data) VALUES('$_values')");



 db.close();

?>
```