# not able to work with httppost in android

Tags: android, http-post

i want to send email and password to php url but i am not able to do this.. i want to get strings from edittext and send it to PHP myadmin localhost i tried alot but not able to do this...  please help me with complete explanation ... thanks :)

```html
<?php
//error_reporting(0);

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('sample_app_ws',$con);

// Insert Query For Send Value To Data Base
//echo $_REQUEST['act'] ;
if(isset($_REQUEST['act']) && $_REQUEST['act'] == 'Insert_UserData') { 
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'];

 $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
 
$result= mysql_query("INSERT INTO  sample_login(email,password,enterDate) VALUES ('".$email."','".$password."',NOW())");
 if($result)   
 $sendvale ['DataSubmit'] = "DataSubmit";
 else $sendvale ['err'] = "ErrDataSubmit";
 echo json_encode($sendvale);
}
elseif(isset($_REQUEST['act']) && $_REQUEST['act'] == 'Select_UserName'){
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
 $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
 
 $result = mysql_query("Select * from sample_login where email = '".$email."' and password = '".$password."'");
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
  $sendvale ['personaldetails'] = "VaildUsrNameAndPassword";
  echo json_encode($sendvale);
 }else{
  $sendvale ['personaldetails'] = "InVaildUsrNameAndPassword";
  echo json_encode($sendvale);
 }
}
else{
  $sendvale ['err'] = "POST_DATA_IS_Empty";
  echo json_encode($sendvale);
 }

?>
```

provide me with android java code which relates to this php code ..

java code....

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private EditText userName;
private EditText password;
private Button submit;
private Button cancel;
public static final String URL = " http://127.0.0.1/sample_app_ws/sample_login.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    createObjects();
}

private void createObjects() {

    userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextpassword);
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCAncel);

}

private void sendData(String userName, String Password) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> arrayList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", userName));
    arrayList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(arrayList));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);

        // httpResponse.getEntity().equals("0");

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendData(userName.getText().toString(), password.getText()
                    .toString());
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: i correctly Dont know i used some code from the net which is using Listvalue pair and httpclient and post methods but nothing happening not even the log is printing any thing... can you provide me some code snippet of android java which supprt my php code

Comment: What is your Java code?

Comment: see my java code i have posted it...

Comment: @segarci  u there ?? did u get my code ? anything u want to suggest to me about my code ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this :

```
public static final String URL = " http://127.0.0.1/sample_app_ws/sample_login.php";
```

to your IP address like this -

```
public static final String URL = " http://your IP address/sample_app_ws/sample_login.php";
```

Go to cmd - write IPConfig and get your ip address.

Comment: Look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27655786/android-values-upload-database-with-json/27656738#27656738

Comment: do we always need to add. jSonparser class and in your code your u arre adding only values ... for that i have to convert hp code but i want the same php code doesnot wana change it...